# htaccess Rewrite Rule effecting non visible links

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a Joomla based website and I use .htaccess to redirect non www,https urls to www,https versions using the rule below:

`RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
 RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]`

Each article has facebook comments code added manually which points to old non ssl urls:

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://www.example.com/links/main_folder/sub_folder/" data-width="625" data-numposts="5" data-colorscheme="light" data-order-by="reverse_time"></div>
```

Everything was working fine however recently I noted that even the links from Facebooks data-href start redirecting to https which results in losing of old comments.

My questions is how can I modifiy the rule which does not effect links from data-href, there is a diference between old urls structure compared to new ones the old ones uses underscores and new ones hyphens if it helps.
Is there a way to excplude links with underscores from this rule? How ever I have pictures that uses underscores also which I do not want to redriect.

Comment: Can you define more precise (exact) condition what you don't want to be redirected?

Comment: I do not want these to redirect:
http://www.example.com/links/main_folder/
http://www.example.com/links/main_folder/sub_folder/

These links are not linked anywhere on pages but only exist in fb-comments data-href tag.

Comment: You can try adding another condition just above RewriteRule: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/links/main_folder`

Comment: @ Dusan Bajic This not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

If it's only without underscores, you can use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !_
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Unfortuantely not working. Can this be Joomla or something else causing this ? I checked Global Configuration > Server > Force SSL is none.